# Rate of deformation on Compressible and Non-Newtonian Fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Couple of weeks ago, I asked if the rate of deformation magnitude is the right one (Please see the link : [How to calculate Shear Rate magnitude for Compressible Flow?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/404032/165563))

Now, in order to express the apparent viscosity on compressible domain, I do some researches about how to find the magnitude of the strain rate by finding the second invariant but it seems it does never include the expansion/dilatation terms in compressible flow.

So, I am confused about the right term to use and I'd like to know how to take into account the dilatation rate of deformation when modeling the apparent viscosity of a compressible and non newtonian flow?

Thanks

Comment: The expansion/dilation portion of the fluid deformation is isotropic (equal strain rates in the three principal directions of deformation rate tensor), which does not involve any shear.  So, if you are saying that it is shear that is the cause of  non-Newtonian fluid response, the expansion/diluation would not contribute (e.g., to purely viscous non-Newtonian fluid model behavior).  However, in real fluid behavior (not model behavior), it is not in general expected that shear is the entire story, and much more complicated models should be considered.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Thanks a lot for this explanation. So, if we assume that the non-newtonian behaviour results purely from the shear deformation rate, so we are not supposed to take into account the expansion term which results only from volume change (during a shock wave for example).

Comment: Gases, which are typically involved with shock waves, are not usually regarded as non-Newtonian.  And non-Newtonian liquids, which are typically considered incompressible, won’t exhibit shock waves.

Comment: @ChesterMiller i forgot to ask you in regards to my previous post about shear rate magnitude (link above). It seemed that you agree with the formula except the 2 factor. Yet, the expansion term is not supposed to be there?

Comment: It's a judgment call.  I would use a version without the dilation terms (or a separate term for the dilatation...as in the case of Newtonian fluids).  More generally, if you are trying to describe the behavior of a purely viscous non-Newtonian fluid, all three invariants of the rate of deformation tensor should be considered for involvement.  I know of no non-Newtonian models that actually do this.  This is probably because there are no real fluids that exhibit purely viscous non-Newtonian behavior.  Typically, the fluids are also going to exhibit viscoelasticity.